# How to change the value of a field inside the scope in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have the following model

```
 public class Post
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public List<Images> Images { get; set; }
    }
```

The Image has the following model:

```
public class Images
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following controller that returns posts:

```
function PostsCtrl($http, $scope, datacontext, $timeout {
        $scope.posts = [];

        datacontext.getPosts().then(function (posts) {
            console.log('posts', posts);
            $scope.posts = posts;
}, function(reason) {
        alert(reason);
    });
```

What I am asking is: How to reach to the property of the image through the scope and change it ?

I am thinking of smth like this: `$scope.post.image.path = "google.com" + $scope.post.image.path`

Can I do this in the controller or in my view? I have tried to manipulate with it but no luck.

Comment: This is not enough information to answer your question. Your code looks like c# but you are referring to angular. Please clarify

Comment: I am using angular in the front end and c# backend

Comment: So what exactly are you asking for help with? If you need help with c#, your question should be tagged as such. If your question is clearer, you will get much more help.

Comment: Let me update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's $scope.path it would be possible in your controller doing something like:

```
$scope.path = 'google.com' + $scope.path;
```

Considering your updated question you will want to loop over your posts and change their structure before assigning them to $scope.

```
datacontext.getPosts().then(function (posts) {
 for(var i = posts.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
  posts[i].images[0].path = 'google.com' + posts[i].images[0].path;
 }

 $scope.posts = posts;
 }, function(reason) {
    alert(reason);
 });
```

Comment: If it doesn't work I'll be happy to jump in a chat with you to solve it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I added 

posts[i].images[0].path = 'google.com' + posts[i].image[0].path;

I have a lists of Images. However your approach was the correct one .

Please update your answer, so someone can use it :)